# Can't change the JTextField text

Tags: java, jtextfield

I usually write the code in C#, and I even have the application finished in C#, but I need to port it to Java.

Just started out today, never really used Java before.

The problem is quite strange because I do not get any error it just does not update, here's the code:

```
public void setInfoStrip(String infoStrip) {
    InfoStrip.setText(infoStrip);
}
```

The above is a Setter that should update the JTextField (and it does if I update it using the ActionListener for a button), but it does not update the text when I call it in a class or even in the main(String[] args) entry point of application using this code:

```
mainGUI GUI = new mainGUI();
GUI.setInfoStrip("test");
```

or this code:

```
new mainGUI().setInfoStrip("test");
```

My guess is that it does nothing becuase I call it from a static class

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

But even if I create a new class that's not static and reference it from the public staitc void main(String[] args) then put either

```
mainGUI GUI = new mainGUI();
GUI.setInfoStrip("test");
```

or

```
new mainGUI().setInfoStrip("test");
```

It the newly created class, which I call by

```
new ImGoingToCry().Alot();
```

It still does nothing.

I'm confused as hell, I even read some problems connected with this on google but they were all solved by this:

```
mainGUI GUI = new mainGUI();
GUI.setInfoStrip("test");
```

Here's the MVCE that some of you requested:

```
public class mainGUI {
// GUI Elements
private JPanel WorkSpace;
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane1;
private JList DetectedProfiles;
private JButton StartGame;
private JTextField CurProf;
private JButton BackupProfiles;
private JButton SearchSaves;
private JButton RetrieveProfiles;
private JTextField InfoStrip;
private JLabel ProfileSize;

/**
 * Getter and Setter functions
 */
public void setInfoStrip(String infoStrip) {
    InfoStrip.setText(infoStrip);
}


// Initialize the main application GUI and set it's properties
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame mainGUIFrame = new JFrame("The Witcher 3 Save Manager | " + " ver. "  + GlobalVariables.appversion);
    mainGUIFrame.setContentPane(new mainGUI().WorkSpace);
    mainGUIFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainGUIFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainGUIFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420, 370));
    mainGUIFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainGUIFrame.pack();
    mainGUIFrame.setVisible(true);
    new mainGUI().run();
}


public void run() {
    /**
     * Initialize the core application functions
     */
    // Load the application settings
    GlobalVariables.Settings();
    // Initialize the app components
    GlobalVariables.Initialize();

    // Pass the value to setter
    new mainGUI().setInfoStrip("test"); // This should change the text but it does nothing there's not even an error
}
}
```

Comment: Please post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example). Not all small snippets of code. You can edit your post by clicking the `edit` link below you question.

Comment: What is `InfoStrip`? Is that the name of the `JTextField` variable you want to set text of, or is that a class you created (that possibly has a static method called `setText()`)? Just to be clear. BTW, as already said, [mcve] please.

Comment: Just posted the MVCE sorry for not doing it ealier. I'm sure that the solution's pretty simple but I'm either too blind or too dumb to figure it out.

Comment: @Marcin your MCVE doesn't even run. What is `GlobalVariables`? Can you give a link to your entire code? I think this can be solved without using the document listener too. BTW, you may want to follow java class/variable naming conventions. Yours looks more like C# ;-)

Comment: The `GlobalVariables` is my own class which's is working just fine, you may even skip that it has nothing to do with the JTextField. The DocumentListener works fine but it seems as it's just quite a bit of effort to update the text in a simple text field. If you have any suggestions on how to solve it without using the DocumentListener just tell me. Also it looks like C# because this is my first time wirting anything in Java.

Comment: @Marcin I had previously known that changing the text should happen without *explicitly* using DocumentListener. So, before seeing your MCVE, I tried out a small program myself and there the text changes w/o DocumentListener. Peek [here](http://pastebin.com/GTdJGE2W). Do you have your code in github or something? If you like maybe I could take a look. BTW, a notification is sent the target recipient *only if he is tagged*.

Comment: No need, your code made me realise that all of it was because of the Intellji GUI builder, I made the GUI myself and it works without DocumentListener. Funny thing that It just work when I used the WindowBuilder in Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will be of help. From javadocs for [JTextComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText-java.lang.String-), from which `JTextField` inherits `setText()` method:

> #### setText
>
> Sets the text of this `TextComponent` to the specified text. If the text is null or empty, has the effect of simply deleting the old text. When text has been inserted, the resulting caret location is determined by the implementation of the caret class.
>
> **Note that text is not a bound property, so no `PropertyChangeEvent` is fired when it changes. To listen for changes to the text, use `DocumentListener`**.

In case you wonder what a [BoundProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html#bound) is:

> A bound property notifies listeners when its value changes. This has
> two implications:
>
> 1. The bean class includes addPropertyChangeListener() and
>    removePropertyChangeListener() methods for managing the bean's
>    listeners.
> 2. When a bound property is changed, the bean sends a
>    PropertyChangeEvent to its registered listeners. PropertyChangeEvent
>    and PropertyChangeListener live in the java.beans package.
>
> The java.beans package also includes a class, PropertyChangeSupport,
> that takes care of most of the work of bound properties. This handy
> class keeps track of property listeners and includes a convenience
> method that fires property change events to all registered listeners.

P.S.: as the OP has not given any [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this sounds relevant. But, I strongly feel the case is going to be otherwise once we see the OP's code.

Comment: Thanks, the document listener fixed the issue, I feel stupid now :)